# Remove "column" form DojoX Grid 1.2

Tags: dojo

is there any way to remove the red marked "select column" from an dojo grid?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific column is used to display the row selector to select rows. To disable that, just set the `rowSelector` property of the grid to `false`.

For example,

```
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({rowSelector:false}, node);
```